# "I have 2 days open next week."

Tags: word-meaning

Can I say

> I have 2 days open next week

to mean that I have 2-day free time next week?

Comment: It should be mentioned: "2 days" and "2-day" are slightly different. "2 days" would be used as a noun phrase, and doesn't necessarily imply that the two days are consecutive. ("I have 2 days open next week: Monday and Thursday.") "2-day" would be used as an adjective, and carries the implication that the days are consecutive ("I have a 2-day vacation next week: Tuesday through Wednesday.")

Answer (score 23):

In the US "open" time ordinarily means time which has not been allotted to meetings or other formal activities and is therefore available for the purpose under discussion.

> I can't meet with them today, but I have tomorrow afternoon open.

"Free" time has pretty much the same meaning in this sort of context—you could say "I have tomorrow afternoon free"—but if you speak of your "free" time in general terms, not tied to a specific timespan, it can also mean your time away from work, time when you are free to do whatever you want:

> I spend a lot of my free time answering questions on ELL.

Time "off" is time when you are released from ordinary obligations. It's usually time when you have permission to be absent from work, and that's probably what you mean:

> I have two days off next week.

It's also used for shortened prison sentences: prisoners get "time off" for good behavior.

Comment: everywhere I have worked in the UK has used "open" to mean not in meetings or other formal work. I think that the distinction is that in open time you have things to do but can put them aside to help with something elsewhere as free implies lack of productive work to do.

Answer (score 0):

Usually open means "not in a meeting or engaged in a scheduled activity".

You could use open, as you have in your example, but what you haven't addressed is, are they consecutive days? Are you working but on a scheduled task.

For example:

Let's meet next week.

Sure, I have 2 days open, Monday and Thursday.

Let's do Thursday at 4pm.

Thursday at 4pm it is.

On the other hand if you're trying to say that you're not working for two days, generally you would say something like "two days off" or "I'm not working two days next week." The latter is a bit more common when schedules change a lot.

Example:

So we can we go on our hiking trip?

I have two days off next week, we can go then.

Sounds good to me, I'll start packing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may say that as the listener will unambiguously be aware of your intent.

However, you may try:

1. I have two days free next week.
2. I have a two-day span (or period) free (or open) next week.
3. I am free for two days next week.

If you are speaking of scheduling and wish to indicate that you have room to be engaged, choose 2.

If you want to indicate that you will be away from some regularly scheduled task or event, such as work or school, in order to rest, relax or play, choose 1 or 3. If those days are consecutive, choose 3. Otherwise, replace the "for two days" with the specific days.

If your writing is informal, "two" may be replaced with the numeral.

If the writing is formal, I would include "which" or "that" after "day," as appropriate.

Comment: I actually wanted to ask my customer who is also a friend of mine if I could schedule a visit to her company because a meeting with other customer was cancelled so I will have two days open in my schedule.

Comment: You are fine to say, "I have two days open next week," in your conversation to schedule an event. You would probable add, "Which is better for you, Monday or Tuesday?"

Answer (score 0):

I would generally not use phrases that are not very clear in the first place or those that are ambiguous.

In this instance, I would say just say: I am free on Wednesday and Friday next week. This has the added attraction of being more explicit and informative.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't! It does not make any sense to me.

There are other ways to tell that. *One of them* could be...

> I'm free for two days next week.

Comment: I think "I have two days off in the next week" can be an option, too

Comment: @Cardinal having two days 'off' in *India* means you are not going to office. **And,** that not necessarily mean that you are free! Say, I take two days 'off' for doing domestic work!

Comment: You really wouldn't understand "I have two days open next week"? I would expect any native English speaker (and most ESL speakers) to understand this pretty easily.

Comment: Interesting that you haven't seen this before, but it's a widely-used idiom. See Meaning 10 at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/open): "unengaged or unoccupied ⇒ _the doctor has an hour open for you to call"_

Comment: True, have never ever come across this! @J.R. 'open' I think is used for 'places'. If people are *open*, I'd think that you want to make them boyfriend/girlfriend! Say, *"is she open?"* .... Yeah, she has no boyfriend, you can try!

Comment: @TylerH spot on! I'll *still* not understand this even though natives explain...because to me, if a girl or boy is *open*, you can surely try to make her/him boyfriend. As I said to JR in my other comment!

Comment: @MaulikV BTW, as a native English speaker I've never heard anyone refer to a single person (read: without a boyfriend or girlfriend) as "open". "is she open?" would need to be followed with "to dating/a relationship", e.g. "is she open to [the idea of] a relationship [with the right person (e.g. me)]"

Comment: @TylerH [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/open) entry #15 says -  **not already** taken, occupied, or **engaged** - so, if *she's* not engaged with someone, she's *'open'*. May not be *formal*, but I'm pretty certain that I've heard this several times in the context of 'open' for relationship.

Comment: @MaulikV You are misunderstanding the meaning of *engaged* there. It doesn't mean "to be wed" in that context, it means "doing something"; the [primary](https://www.google.com/search?q=engaged&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1jfPDvL3NAhWp44MKHVl5CkAQBQgbKAA) [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/engage).

Comment: @TylerH I'd consider 'engaged' as 'reserved' if it is opposite to 'open' as far as relationships are concerned. If you are 'taken' by someone, you are 'not available' and thus, you are 'open'.

Comment: @MaulikV Open is not used to mean the opposite of taken in that sentence structure; available is. Open has inappropriate connotations, or needs more context (as I said before, she could be open *to the idea of* a relationship. But to say "she is open for relationships" is offensive, like she is a shop or a product to be had. It dehumanizes them, kind of like how saying "frisst" instead of "isst" in German dehumanizes a person by saying they are eating like an animal. I strongly recommend that you don't refer to women as "open" when they are single.